# Quitar más de un caracter específico en una lista en C#

Tags: c#

Quiero que en mi lista se conserven los datos cuando tienen más de 2 `-`.

Ejemplo:

```
1251081569156-01  
1251081569156-02  
1251081569156-03-01  
1251081569156-03-02
```

y solo quiero conservar estos:

```
1251081569156-03-01  
1251081569156-03-02
```

Tengo de aquí esto, pero ya no sé cómo proseguir:

```
DatosVtex datospedidos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatosVtex> 
(streamReader.ReadToEnd());      
var listsplit = datospedidos.PedidosVtex;
var listasvtexs = (from l in listsplit select l.pedido).ToList();                                                                          
var elementoscon2guiones = listasvtexs.FindAll(x=> x.Contains("-"));
```

Comment: ¿Qué es "listasvtexs"?
Si puedes agregar un poco más de tu codigo estaría genial

Comment: Es solo una lista de un response de donde obtengo unos datos. anexo:                                                   DatosVtex datospedidos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatosVtex>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());               
              
                var listsplit = datospedidos.PedidosVtex;                        
                var listasvtexs = (from l in listsplit select l.pedido).ToList();                                      var elementoscon2guiones = listasvtexs.FindAll(x=> x.Contains("-"));

Comment: Puedes usar `regex`... puedes hacer un `.Split("-").Length == 3`... Puedes hacer un `for` donde se compare cada letra con el guión y llevar un `contador++`... Puedes hacer un `while (contadorGuiones < 2)`... Puedes hacer un `.Replace("-", string.Empty).Contains("-");`... Hay mil maneras de hacerlo, desde las más simples hasta las más descabelladas, como en este comentario. Con la primera y la segunda debería bastar...

Comment: ya que estas usando linq puedes usar un contador, int count = source.Count(f => f == '-'); con eso aplicas un filtro y listo.

Comment: De los datos que se pueden conservar, ¿existe la posibilidad que se repitan en la lista antes que la filtres?

Comment: Hola Angel, podrias marcar como aceptada la respuesta que mas util te haya resultado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esto obtendrá los elementos que tengan el caracter "-":

```
var elementoscon2guiones = listasvtexs.FindAll(x=> x.Contains("-"));
```

La solución es simplemente detectar los elementos que tengan más de una vez el character "-" a partir de la lista `listasvtexs` y agregarlos a tu lista `elementoscon2guiones`:

```
    foreach(var elemento in listasvtexs)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(elemento, "-"); //busca coincidencias.
        if(matches.Count>1){ //revisa si el caracter exista más de una vez.
            elementoscon2guiones.Add(elemento);
        }
    }
```

de esta forma, la lista `elementoscon2guiones` tendrá únicamente los elementos:

```
1251081569156-03-01
1251081569156-03-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto mi sugerencia.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> listasvtexs = new List<string>() { //--> Aquí generé la lista con los ejemplos que diste para poder replicar tu problema
            "1251081569156-01",
            "1251081569156-02",
            "1251081569156-03-01",
            "1251081569156-03-02"
        };
        int contador=0;
        bool confirmar = false;
        List<string> elementoscon2guiones= new List<string>()
        foreach (var i in listasvtexs) //-->Verifica cada palabra de tu lista
        {
            foreach(char v in i) //-->Verifica cada caracter de cada palabra de tu lista
            {
                if(v == '-')
                {
                    contador++; //-->Si se encuentra el caracter "-" en la palabra que se está verificando, se suma a la variable
                }
                if (contador == 2) //-->Si durante la busqueda, se encontró dos veces, se confirma que es un dato valido
                    confirmar = true;
            }
            if (confirmar == true)
                elementoscon2guiones.Add(i); //-->Finalmente, si fue un dato valido, se agrega a la lista elementoscon2guiones
            contador = 0;
            confirmar = false; //-->Se reinician los valores de verificación
        }
    }
```

Pueden haber otras formas de hacerlo pero te comparto mi idea. Todo está explicado en los comentarios del codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Usando **Linq** es muy fácil, solo debes hacer esto:

```
listOriginal.RemoveAll(item => item.Count(i => i == '-') < 2);
```

De esta forma eliminamos de la lista todos los elementos que tengan menos de **2 guiones**. Utilizamos el **método Count** para contar la cantidad de guiones que tiene cada elemento de la lista y posteriormente usando el **método RemoveAll** borramos todos los elementos cuyo total de guiones es menor que **2**, dejando en la lista solamente los elementos que tienen **2** guiones o más.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```